# Could not use Provider.of in child widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have my main() like this with MultiProvider wrapped with LocalizedApp for localization:

```
void main() async {
  setupLocator();
  var delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
    fallbackLocale: 'fa',
    supportedLocales: ['fa'],
  );
  FluroRouter.setupRouter();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: true);
  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      delegate,
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<ConnectionStatus>(
            create: (context) =>
                ConnectivityService().connectivityController.stream,
            initialData: ConnectionStatus.offline,
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => AppState(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and MyApp class is as follows again wrapped with LocalizationProvider:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appstate = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
    var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: appstate.statusBarColor,
    ));

    return LocalizationProvider(
      state: LocalizationProvider.of(context).state,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            localizationDelegate
          ],
          supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
          locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
          theme: appstate.currentTheme,
          initialRoute: 'landing',
          onGenerateRoute: FluroRouter.router.generator,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but even in the initial route which is 'landing' when I try to use a `Provider.of<AppState>(context)` it throws this error:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppState> above this Landing Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Landing is under your MultiProvider/Provider<AppState>.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.

  For example, instead of:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }

  consider using `builder` like so:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builer: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here!
also I'm using Fluro v.1.5.1 for navigation.

Comment: The context created by the main runApp is different from the context of the MaterialAppp (which creates its own), if you want to use it in both try wrapping it again with a ChangeNotifierProvider.value() and pass it before the MaterialApp

Comment: @EdwynZN You mean wrap the MaterialApp in ChangeNotifierProvider.value() or in the widget I'm trying to use "Provider.of"?

Comment: The MaterialAppp, maybe something is off with the LocalizationProvider, can you share how does that LocalizationProvider works?